Hosting Ollama on a Kaggle Notebook with Ngrok: OpenWebUI Not Connecting to Ollama Client
I'm hosting Ollama on a Kaggle notebook and using Ngrok to create a tunnel, allowing me to connect to the Ollama client on my local machine via the command line. The Ngrok tunnel works as expected, and I can interact with the Ollama client through it.
To expand the setup, I created a new environment and installed OpenWebUI for Ollama using pip (not Docker). However, when I start OpenWebUI, it fails to connect to the Ollama client, even though the Ngrok tunnel is active and functional.
I followed this tutorial to set up the system, adjusted the LD_LIBRARY_PATH according to kaggle: https://youtu.be/Qa1h7ygwQq8?si=wh1U3TODeSb6O_0c.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Verified the Ngrok tunnel URL is correct and accessible.
Ensured the Kaggle notebook is running and Ollama is operational.
Despite this, OpenWebUI doesn’t seem to recognize or connect to Ollama.
This is the notebook I'm using :- [https://www.kaggle.com/code/singh008/ollama-server]
NOTE :- same thing happens on colab as well
What might be causing this issue? Do I need specific configurations in OpenWebUI to work with Kaggle-hosted Ollama via Ngrok?

Open your browser and check first the network section with developer tools. Try to press button to start the chat and check what is the issue. What the request return? It will help you to check whether there is a connection or there is no connection at all. See how to do it in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeSNa1cHB3o

I can use it perfectly from my cmd , but when run the open-webui serve command it can't connect to that session which is running in cmd

Have you set OLLAMA_BASE_URL?

no , i only used the set OLLAMA_HOST= and then I run a model and it works. I can chat from cmd . but the openwebui doesn't connect to that ollama session

See my answer please. The host should be different

can you please tell me the steps clearly so that I can follow. I'm new to ngrok and ollama. Really appreciate the help , Thankyou

https://stackoverflow.com/a/79239303/6799297 See below I answered step by step

@artona thank you very much i worked , the base url trick

I was not able to reproduce your error (double check your ngrok logs - it might be the case as I had 403 Forbidden when I connected my llama endpoint to ngrok first; I needed to set up OLLAMA_HOST).

Ollama endpoint

 OLLAMA_HOST=0.0.0.0 ollama serve

See that host is set. Without it default settings make ollama unable to use ngrok endpoint (only localhost is allowed)

Ngrok

ngrok http http://localhost:11434


OpenWebUI

OLLAMA_BASE_URL=your_ngrok_endpoint open-webui serve

where endpoint is like <your ngrok endpoint in form of https://*.ngrok-free.app>
